# The operation could not be completed. Invalid FORMATETC structure

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am developing web based application using `asp.net` and `ajax`. Today I am facing an issue, while dragging and dropping the ajax based components under the ajax enabled webform.

The error message is

```
The operation could not be completed. Invalid FORMATETC structure
```

If your answer is assembly then please let me know which assembly such issues (be specific about assemblies)

Comment: try this http://dotbert.loedeman.nl/solution-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-invalid-formatetc-structure

Comment: Let me know which assembly is responsible for this error...

Comment: Can you please give a bit more information on what system are you receiving this error? Visual Studio version? Other third party controls / extensions addins involved?
It may be because of the Ajax Control Toolkit but it may be some other library intercepting the drop event as well. FORMATETC is carying out the information you are dragging (image, rtf, object, other) so what is receiving it does not expect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is basically due to Ajax Toolkit assembly if you have added it as toolbox. Only way to get rid of this is to restart your IDE , whenever your have Formatetc error , or unload the toolbox and recreate it. Either of them will solve the. But it will not go. Occurance will become rare. Hope this help.

Ajax toolkit version < 3.5 seen such bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If you using `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` try remove it and redownload and adding again.

Also try re-install [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), which might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

first Check in  control panel => administrative tool => .net framework . your internet priority is low then change it